# Visual Studio 2010 does not open wixproj in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, wix

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed in Windows 8 Pro 64 bit System.

It cannot open the wixproj. The error message is "Setup.wixproj cannot be opened because its Project type (.wixproj) is not supported by this Version of the application.

To open it, please use a Version that supports this type of Project"

Note that the VS2012 in the same System opens it.

I tried repairing the Wix 3.7 Installation without any sucess.

**Anything else I can try?**

Comment: Which version of VS2010? Pro? Express?

Answer (score 2):

Repair of WiX does not seem to help.

However uninstalling and reinstalling Wix fixed the Problem.